# Read after write in Galera

Tags: mysql, galera

I am facing a issue with 3 node galera cluster where the read doesn't return any records even when the write has been commited. Below are the steps which can happen from multiple servers.

1>Server A writes a record at 12:00:00 AM

2>Server B reads the same record after 10 seconds at 12:00:10 AM but doesn't get any record.

The bin log on all 3 server confirms the commit at 12:00:00 AM.

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: commit binlog at 12:00:05 AM.

Comment: didn't get you. the commit statement was written in bin log at 12:00:00.

Comment: That says that all the other nodes _can_ comment _when they get around to it_.

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB/PXC are you running?

Answer (score 1):

This handles the "critical read" problem you describe:

```
SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 1;
SELECT ...
SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 0;
```

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera#critical_reads) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from a node other than then node where the transaction was commit, there is a finite response time on the other nodes from the time it is certified, to the time it is applied on the other node.

In theory you [should be able to wait](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10715?focusedCommentId=113822&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-113822) to ensure its committed.

Comment: in practice if you load balance between db servers, try to make it sticky based on the user connection somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Rick James and danblack both give the right answer.

The easy way:

```
SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 1;
SELECT ...
SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait = 0;
```

This is the method from the official: [Achieving Read-After-Write Semantics With Galera](http://galeracluster.com/2015/06/achieving-read-after-write-semantics-with-galera/).

But, **It is highly recommend that not to read after write. **In this situation, you should check your business logic if it is really have to do this way.