# Row read lock on write

Tags: galera

Suppose I have a Galera cluster with 3 nodes. If I start modifying a table and a client start to read the same table from another node, I want it to wait for the write on the other node to finish. The reason is that, one of the values is a kind of lock and must be read updated. I saw this:

```
SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait=1;
SELECT * FROM example WHERE field = "value";
SET SESSION wsrep_sync_wait=0
```

Is it the right way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read after write in Galera](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217619/read-after-write-in-galera)

Comment: The suggested post is the one I yanked this code from actually. I wanted to confirm this is exactly what must be done in my scenario. @dbdemon

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what you have to do.

Comment: More than that I liked to know if my case is a normal scenario.

Comment: I suppose it's not unheard of. Anecdotally, devs at my workplace have considered using this approach. You can also do Google searches on "wsrep_sync_wait" or "read after write" which seem to yield relatively large result sets.

Answer (score -2):

It will be a lot easier to add an extra layer of proxy to ensure that your downstream programs always read from nodes that are synced and ready. I recommend adding maxscale. Mine is like this:

[image]

It's really easy and will make your galera cluster so much more stable. I used to have lots of "wrep not ready" errors and now I have 0 5xx errors after running for over a week.

1. Install Maxscale on one of the nodes or on a separate machine.
2. Create a user `maxscale@'%'` on all the nodes and grand all privileges (well for simplicity).
3. Edit `/etc/maxscale.cnf` and add

```
[server1]
type=server
address=192.168.0.1 #replace with your actual IPv4 address
port=3306

[server2]
type=server
address=192.168.0.2 #replace with your actual IPv4 address
port=3306

[server3]
type=server
address=192.168.0.3 #replace with your actual IPv4 address
port=3306

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=galeramon
servers=server1,server2,server3
user=maxscale
password=H5T9R2M6Z1Q0
monitor_interval=2s

[Read-Write-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=server1,server2,server3
user=maxscale
password=your_password

[Read-Write-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Write-Service
protocol=mariadbprotocol
port=4006
```

4. Restart maxscale `systemctl restart maxscale`

Now modify your downstream codes and connect to 127.0.0.1, port 4006 and you are done.

It's better to let the server admin guys worry about server things. It's easier and less prone to bugs.